# XML error with no valuable information

Tags: xml, odoo-8, odoo

what is wrong with my code? error doesn't give any valuable information unfortunately

File "src/lxml/lxml.etree.pyx", line 3501, in lxml.etree.*Validator.assert* (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:194922)

AssertionError: Element openerp has extra content: data, line 3

```
<openerp>
    <data>



        <record id="account_payment_cash_turnover_analysis_osv" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">account_payment_cash turnover analysis osv</field>
            <field name="model">account.payment.cash.turnover.analysis.osv</field>
            <field name="type">form</field>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <form string="Turnover Analysis">
                    <field name="date_from" />
                    <field name="date_to" />
                    <group colspan="4">
                        <field name="comp_currency" />
                    </group>
                    <footer>
                        <button name="process" string="OK" type="object" class="oe_highlight"/>
                        or
                        <button string="Cancel" class="oe_link" special="cancel"/>
                    </footer>
                </form>
            </field>
        </record>


        <wizard
                id="wizard_balance"
                model="payment.mode"
                name="account_payment_cash.balance"
                string="Balance" />

        <menuitem
                icon="STOCK_PRINT"
                action="wizard_balance"
                id="menu_wizard_balance"
                parent="menu_report_banks"/>


        <act_window name="Turnover Analysis"
                    res_model="account.payment.cash.turnover.analysis.osv"
                    view_mode="form"
                    view_type="form"
                    target="new"
                    id="act_account_wizard_reconcile_entries_osv"/>

        <menuitem
                parent="menu_report_banks"
                action="act_account_wizard_reconcile_entries_osv"
                icon="STOCK_JUSTIFY_FILL"
                id="menu_act_account_wizard_reconcile_entries_osv" />



    </data>
</openerp>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no conversion for tag `wizard` in Odoo's xml import. And that is the error telling you: `wizard` is content which isn't expected by the import.

So change:

```xml
<wizard
    id="wizard_balance"
    model="payment.mode"
    name="account_payment_cash.balance"
    string="Balance" />
```

to:

```xml
<record id="wizard_balance" model="payment.mode">
    <field name="name">account_payment_cash.balance</field>
    <field name="string">Balance</field>
</record>
```

I don't know, if the field names are correct, but i bet you get the idea now.

Comment: that makes sense:)

Answer (score 0):

Try to change line3 to:

```
<record name="account_payment_cash_turnover_analysis_osv" model="ir.ui.view">
```

When browsing the internet you will find plenty of people having this kind of "issue". For example:

https://github.com/odoo/odoo/issues/14451